# Como requisitar access token do servidor, apenas via frontend de forma segura, sem interação humana?

Tags: javascript, rest, front-end, autenticação, token

Boas galera.

Travei nisso aqui:
Tenho uma aplicação no frontend de um servidor, que precisa se comunicar com uma API Rest em outro servidor, sem que o cliente tenha que logar. O app que irá requisitar ou enviar o que seja necessário para autenticar. Esta API gera tokens para autorização.
como requisitar o token de forma segura, via frontend e guarda-lo com segurança também ?
Agradeço a atenção

Comment: 1 - Se a APi que voce vai consultar tiver suporte a https, otimo, por que ate onde sei não tem muito o que você possa fazer somente no lado do cliente.

2 - Armazenar o token de forma segura, vou aguardar por uma resposta tambem, eu não conheco nada no momento para isso.

Comment: Oi Neuber , muito obrigado pela rápida resposta. Minha vantagem é que esta API, somos nós quem estamos desenvolvendo, então, sim poderei utilizar o HTTPS. Como não tenho muita experiência com isso, poderia me enviar algum link de como poderia ser implementado isso via https?

Comment: Achei algo que pode ser interessante, estou lendo ainda, mas segue ai para você dar uma olhada também Neuber: https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa e tem esse e esse aqui https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Answer (score 1):

> Tenho uma aplicação no frontend de um servidor, que precisa se comunicar com uma API Rest em outro servidor, sem que o cliente tenha que logar.

Estou assumindo que você quer dizer que em um servidor `S` você tem uma aplicação web `WA`, composta tanto de um *back-end* quanto um *front-end*.

> O app que irá requisitar ou enviar o que seja necessário para autenticar.

Por app, eu entendo a parte *back-end* da applicação web.

> Esta API gera tokens para autorização. como requisitar o token de forma segura, via frontend e guarda-lo com segurança também?

Se você deseja segurança, nunca gerencie *tokens* no lado *client* - aliás, nunca confie na integridade do lado *client*. Sugestão de implementação:

- Mantenha as credencias de aplicação (chave secreta, ID de aplicação, etc.) no back-end *exclusivamente*.
- Se o usuário da aplicação `WA` precisa de conteúdo customizado da API REST remota, obtenha as credenciais remotas e armazene-as no *back-end* (ex. Usuário `U1`, token remoto `{4258041c-0180-4bdf-8f5f-962021225eca}`).
- Sua aplicação web deve relizar chamadas apenas para seu próprio *back-end*; se você precisar de conteúdo da API REST remota, faça uma conexão a partir do *back-end*.

Comment: Oi, @MeiaEsquerda. Agradeço a atenção. Mas não tenho acesso ao servidor "S", só possuo acesso ao frontend "WA". O por enquanto, minha idéia é criar um acesso temporario, para "WS" quando ela solicitar. Validando a origem, delegando então para um usuário permanente criado previamente na API. E guardando o token retornado em um cookie httpOnly de expiração breve, pois pelo menos não fica exposto a javascript. Agradeço a atenção e se alguém tiver uma idéia melhor, sou todo ouvidos.